# How do I trigger a test POST for an API-created webhook?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I was testing my handmade webhooks from the admin panel okay, but now that I've created one using the API, how do I initiate a test POST?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I've figured out a solution to my question, and found out after some digging around that you have to enter 1, 2, or 3 as the credit card number to generate an order in my test shop, hence, firing off the POST request for my API created orders/paid webhook.

Thanks,
Kevin